# Laravel Eloquent - Inserting multiple objects at once

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm creating multiple (sometimes hundreds, sometimes thousands) Eloquent objects by reading a CSV file.

Take this loop for instance:

```
$cities = [];
while ($city = readNextCity()) {
  $cities[] = $city;
}
// ok how do I save all $cities without calling $city->save() on each?
```

We know that inserting multiple rows in one query is much more efficient than inserting 1 row per query.  However, is there a way to insert multiple eloquent objects at once so that they get translated to one query? (If not, I don't mind writing it, but I don't want to duplicate efforts).

Comment: No, you can't save Eloquent models at once. You should use `Connection` method `insert` that accepts array of arrays corresponding to the columns. So unless you really need to build those `Models`, don't, instead build an array and pass it to `insert` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the query builder for this.

```
$cities = array();
$i=0;
while ($city = readNextCity()) {
  $cities[$i++] = array('city' => $city);
}

DB::table('city')->insert($cities);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Ok will try it out. FYI in PHP you don't need to explicitly set the array keys like that. $cities[] would use the next available array key.

Comment: You can also read about the above here :- http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#inserts

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.  Oddly Eloquent doesn't translate the object fields into database columns: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `cities` (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) values `

Comment: can you please write your code and table structure here ? Because its look like the column on which values should be inserted are not correctly assigned.